# Internet Explorer and Edge are renaming ".TGZ" files to ".GZ"

Tags: browser, internet-explorer, download

I've had an issue reported by users on the Jenkins system I've installed at my new company.  When downloading release files with the extension ".tgz" (tar'd gzip'd files from Linux), these files are having their file extension renamed to ".gz" by MS Internet Explorer and Edge browsers when we download them.

I've reproduced this on IE.  If you just left-click on the download link, it automatically and silently renames the file it downloads to ".gz".  If you right-click and select "Save target as", the default extension is ".gz".  I don't have anything with Edge, but I've no reason to doubt the report.

I did some investigation to see whether I could narrow it down...

- I wondered if this was an issue with the Nginx reverse proxy doing something strange with MIME types, so I turned off the Nginx service and pointed IE at "http://my.internal.jenkins.server:8080" (not the real name of the link, of course, but you can't see it because it's behind our firewall).  Again though, IE saved the ".tgz" files with extension ".gz".
- I wondered if it was an issue with Jenkins, so I went looking for another file to download.  [Downloading a Moodle release](https://download.moodle.org/releases/latest/) as tgz, again I get it saved with extension ".gz".  So it seems to be a general issue with the browser, not with my Jenkins server.
- **Edit:** Repeated this with files from other locations online...

  - https://varnish-cache.org/_downloads/varnish-5.2.1.tgz downloads correctly on Edge.
  - https://www.arb-silva.de/fileadmin/silva_databases/qiime/Silva_104_release.tgz downloads correctly on Edge.
  - https://files.zimbra.com/downloads/8.6.0_GA/zcs-patch-8.6.0_GA_1162.tgz downloads correctly on Edge.
  - https://www.coin-or.org/download/source/Ipopt/Ipopt-3.3.3.tgz does not download correctly on Edge.
  - http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lapack-3.7.0.tgz does not download correctly on Edge.
  - http://gmsh.info/src/gmsh-1.49.0-source.tgz does not download correctly on Edge.
- I've tried the same thing on Chrome (on Windows) and Firefox (on Ubuntu).  Both download the ".tgz" file correctly.  So it seems to be specific to MS browsers.
- Selecting "Copy shortcut", the URL definitely finishes ".tgz".  Even if you download the file and let IE rename it to ".gz", if you go to the "Downloads" list and check the link, again it reports the URL is ".tgz".
- The file content is unchanged.  Changing the name back when downloading, or renaming the file after downloading, it works fine.
- I've hit Google, of course.  The following are the closest I've found, but they don't seem to have a solution.

  - https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8475572/
  - https://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1403674

This is not an issue I noticed with the Jenkins setup at my previous company.  That said though, at my previous company we had a policy of using Chrome or Firefox in preferences to IE, so it's entirely possible that the issue existed there and we just never noticed it.  My real job is embedded software, so devops is not something I have deep skills in.

Does anyone have any insights into this, please?

Comment: Check HTTP headers of the reponse. [`Content-Disposition: attachment`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition#As_a_response_header_for_the_main_body) header can be used to suggest a name for downloaded files. Maybe Jenkins suggests wrong extension via header and some browsers accept it, while others extract extension from URL. You can easily capture headers with [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler).

Comment: I have used the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/omhhjsoy/3/) from your first link, and Edge downloaded it just fine it as `.tgz`. IE is going very slow, but the temporary name does have `.tgz` in it. As your second link says, the header files are everything here, so please add all your headers to the post for checkup. The jsfiddle does not have any headers, so the browsers don't muck it up.

Comment: @gronostaj Thanks - I'll have a look at that.

Comment: @harrymc Interestingly, your Lenovo download works fine, but the Moodle download from my post doesn't.  As you both say, that does suggest it's a server setup thing.  It's still very odd, especially since users of other software (e.g. Moodle) don't seem to have noticed it.

Comment: @harrymc Ah, I misunderstood what you both meant.  You meant it might be an issue with the HTTP headers in the page showing me the links.  But entering just the download link into the address bar on a new tab, I get the same behaviour.  And I get the same behaviour from the Moodle download.  So I suspect it is not related to HTTP headers.

Comment: The headers are returned by the server in response to the entered link and tell the browser about the default file-name and its characteristics. You may capture them by developer tools of whatever browser you are using. I think that the server will generate the same headers in all cases, so you may use Chrome or Firefox for their display (I don't know what IE has for such tools).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edge is simply looking at the `Content-type` header to determine what file extension to use, as indicated by [the issue you linked](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/8475572/).

```
Moodle:  application/g-zip  
Varnish: application/octet-stream  
Silva:   application/gzip  
Zimbra:  binary/octet-stream  
lpopt:   application/x-gzip  
lapack:  application/x-gzip  
gmsh:    application/x-gzip
```

So clearly you somehow have a file association for `application/x-gzip` and `application/g-zip`.

Comment: It’s also fascinating how there is only one correct gzip mime type here: `application/gzip`. `application/octet-stream` is also valid though just generic binary, all others are not registered with IANA.

Comment: Cool, thanks.  I'll dig into the Nginx settings and check how I get that to work then - and how I then get that to sort out the *Content-type*.  Like I said, devops isn't really my thing, so I'm winging it a bit. :)

Comment: Technically the mime type is correct as is. It is a gzip file, after all. ;)